# A meteor falls in a Mediterranean-like sea: what is the impact?

Tags: climate, apocalypse, ancient-history, bronze-age

**A meteor with a diameter of 300 meters crashes into the middle of a circular sea with a radius of 1500 km and with a speed of 30 km/s.**

Civilizations (and humanity as a whole) that are situated around this sea have Bronze Age technology. How will the impact influence these civilizations? Will it be a total destruction of humanity, or perhaps result in one bad year?

**And will the civilizations situated around this sea be completely destroyed, or partially destroyed?**

Overall, what are the profound impacts of the event on the marine/terrestrial ecosystem and climate in the long and short term?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The impact will be barely noticeable on planetary scale. The tsunami will cause some damage, but nothing irreversible or long lasting on large scale.

A [meteor impact calculator](https://impact.ese.ic.ac.uk/ImpactEarth/cgi-bin/crater.cgi?dist=1500&distanceUnits=1&diam=300&diameterUnits=1&pdens=&pdens_select=8000&vel=30&velocityUnits=1&theta=90&tdens=1000&wdepth=1000&wdepthUnits=1) can answer your question on the effects of the impact

> **Your Inputs:**
>
> - Distance from Impact: 1500.00 km ( = 932.00 miles )
> - Projectile diameter: 300.00 meters ( = 984.00 feet )
> - Projectile Density: 8000 kg/m3
> - Impact Velocity: 30.00 km per second ( = 18.60 miles per second )
> - Impact Angle: 90 degrees
> - Target Density: 1000 kg/m3
> - Target Type: Liquid water of depth 1000.0 meters ( = 3280.0 feet ), over crystalline rock.
>
> **Atmospheric Entry:**
>
> - The projectile begins to breakup at an altitude of 23300 meters = 76400 ft
> - The projectile reaches the ground in a broken condition. The mass of projectile strikes the surface at velocity 29.8 km/s = 18.5 miles/s
> - The energy lost in the atmosphere is $5.93 \times 10^{17}$ Joules = $1.42 \times 10^2 $ MegaTons.
> - The impact energy is $5.03 \times 10^{19} $Joules = $1.20 \times 10^4$ MegaTons.
> - The larger of these two energies is used to estimate the airblast damage.
> - The broken projectile fragments strike the ground in an ellipse of dimension 0.357 km by 0.357 km
>
> **Crater Dimensions:**
>
> - The crater opened in the water has a diameter of 13.1 km ( = 8.17 miles ).
> - For the crater formed in the seafloor: Crater shape is normal in spite of atmospheric crushing; fragments are not significantly dispersed.
> - Transient Crater Diameter: 6.31 km ( = 3.92 miles )
> - Transient Crater Depth: 2.23 km ( = 1.39 miles )
> - Final Crater Diameter: 8.07 km ( = 5.01 miles )
> - Final Crater Depth: 555 meters ( = 1820 feet )
> - The crater formed is a complex crater.
> - The volume of the target melted or vaporized is 0.15 km3 = 0.0359 miles3
> - Roughly half the melt remains in the crater, where its average thickness is 4.78 meters ( = 15.7 feet ).
> - The crater opened in the water has a diameter of 13.1 km ( = 8.17 miles ).
>
> **Thermal Radiation:**
>
> - The fireball is below the horizon. There is no direct thermal radiation.
>
> **Seismic Effects:**
>
> - The major seismic shaking will arrive approximately 5 minutes after impact.
> - Richter Scale Magnitude: 7.0
> - Mercalli Scale Intensity at a distance of 1500 km: Nothing would be felt. However, seismic equipment may still detect the shaking.
>
> **Ejecta:**
>
> - The ejecta will arrive approximately 10.6 minutes after the impact.
> - At your position there is a fine dusting of ejecta with occasional larger fragments
> - Average Ejecta Thickness: 4.21 microns ( = 0.166 thousandths of an inch )
> - Mean Fragment Diameter: 38.7 microns ( = 1.52 thousandths of an inch )
>
> **Air Blast:**
>
> - The air blast will arrive approximately 1.26 hours after impact.
> - Peak Overpressure: 874 Pa = 0.00874 bars = 0.124 psi
> - Max wind velocity: 2.05 m/s = 4.59 mph
> - Sound Intensity: 59 dB (Loud as heavy traffic)
> - Damage Description: Glass windows may shatter.
>
> **Tsunami Wave:**
>
> - The impact-generated tsunami wave arrives approximately 4.2 hours after impact.
> - Tsunami wave amplitude is less than 8.1 meters ( = 26.5 feet).

Comment: *"The impact will be barely noticeable."* except for the last effect.. a Tsunami of 8 meters over a coastal region of 11000 kilometers would be quite devastating !